# Is there an easy way to confirm piston rings are broken?

Tags: oil-leak, piston-ring

My old 2009 car nearly eats more oil than gasoline (I have to top up every few hundred miles). Common causes can be leaks or it is burned due to leaky piston rings.

My car was standing for over three weeks yet there was no visible oil leak on the ground which rules out option 1. On the other hand, I do not notice the exhaust to be super smoky.

I would like to get this fixed. Is there an easy way a mechanic could confirm that the piston rings indeed are the issue and need to replaced before doing an expensive repair?

Also, is there any other big contender for big oil consumption besides leaky piston rings?